# Can anyone explain MPI_Alltoall to me

Tags: mpi

I noticed that it works in a similar way to `MPI_Scatter`.  However, I'm pretty confused about how it distributes data among processes.  Would it be possible to use `MPI_Scatter` in conjunction with another collective function to achieve the same result as `MPI_Alltoall`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the MPI standard (5.8, page 168)

> The j-th block sent from process i is received
>    by process j and is placed in the i-th block of recvbuf
>
> [...]
>
> If comm is an intracommunicator, the outcome is as if each process
>   executed a send to each process (itself included) with a call to,

```
MPI_Send(sendbuf+i * sendcount * extent(sendtype),sendcount,sendtype,i, ...)
```

> and a receive from every other process with a call to

```
MPI_Recv(recvbuf+i * recvcount * extent(recvtype),recvcount,recvtype,i,...)
```

And yes, you can implement `MPI_Alltoall()` with `comm_size` `MPI_Scatter()` if this is what you are asking for.

Comment: With MPI_Send and MPI_Recv you can indicate to which process send the block, but with MPI_Scatter only ROOT (process 0) will send the block of data, so I wonder how can you achieve this????

Comment: You do not need `one` but `comm_size` times `MPI_Scatter()` in which all ranks are root once.